# Outlook Reset Navigation Pane

Tags: powershell, outlook, command-prompt

I have been trying to Automate a PowerShell script for Outlook Navigation Pane Reset But I don't Know exactly what it changes.

I changed the Navigation Options, Views, Folder Pane, reading Pane Settings manually and then I tried OUTLOOK.EXE \resetnavepane from Run, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /resetnavpane From Command Prompt and & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /resetnavpane From Powershell but I see no change in Outlook it just restarts outlook in a new window with the same settings I changed manually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to reset navigation pane for outlook as outlook.exe /resetnavpane does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Outlook keeps its settings in the windows registry keys. You must search for settings in the windows registry instead of relying on the command line arguments. For example, you may find the following thread helpful - [navigation bar moved to left](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/navigation-bar-moved-to-left/m-p/3251517/page/6).